# iPhone - UnAuthorized Access Exception

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios, xamarin

This is a question I am sure Xcode developers could also answer.
I have a screenshot of my code below in Xamarin.

Why am I getting an Unauthorized access exception? I should be able to write to the documents folder right?

[image]

Code:

```
  var webClient = new WebClient();
        //var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal); // iOS 7 and earlier
        var documentsFolder = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
        var fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine (documentsFolder, "verses.xml");


        if(!File.Exists(documentsFolder)){

            Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsFolder);

            if(!File.Exists(fileNameAndPath)){

                //File.SetAttributes(fileNameAndPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Create(fileNameAndPath);
                //Throws exception here.

            }

        }
```

And ERRORs:

Access to the path "/var/mobile/Applications/1F95D694-BBA5-4FB3-AE6C-0C2CDD9DEDD8/comexample.app/verses.xml" is denied

Access to the path '/private/var/mobile/Applications/1F95D694-BBA5-4FB3-AE6C-0C2CDD9DEDD8/Documents/verses.xml' is denied.

I have tried both paths and I get access denied.

Comment: Show your code and exception message as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write to your app's bundle path, the folder is readonly. I'm also not sure where the `Personal` folder points to with Xamarin.iOS.

Use this directory, and you can write to it:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` points (for me at least) to `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ASDF-ASDF-ASDF/Documents`. That also lies within the directory of which you say we cannot write to, right?